# Should the resume be exactly in chronological order?

Tags: resume

A friend of mine switched roles a few months ago, and she feels as though her current job experience is a step down from what her previous role used to be (there is some regret in switching as a result). I am helping her craft her resume again and am wondering whether it is appropriate to mention the previous job experience before the current one, simply because it is more relevant to seeking new jobs in this line and is also more compelling to read. Or do jobs have to be listed in chronological order in a chronological resume (as opposed to a functional resume which we explored but might not be appropriate in her case as she has no gaps in employment and has only worked in 2 companies in the last 7 years) ?

Answer (score 2):

> I am helping her craft her resume again and am wondering whether it is
>   appropriate to mention the previous job experience before the current
>   one, simply because it is more relevant to seeking new jobs in this
>   line and is also more compelling to read. Or do jobs have to be listed
>   in chronological order in a chronological resume

Nothing *has to* be listed in any particular order. A resume is a sales tool that can be crafted in any way you choose.

However anything other than reverse-chronological order for a chronological resume would be confusing at best, and a sign of "this one doesn't understand resume conventions" at worst. A reader might conclude you made a foolish mistake.

If you choose to create a functional resume, you could list the most appropriate functions first.

But if you choose a chronological resume, adhere to the norms and keep things in order. Use a cover letter to point out the most relevant aspects of the applicant's experience - without regard to when they occurred.

As @HorusKol wisely comments: "the resume is history, the cover letter is the sales pitch".

Comment: +1 for the cover letter - the resume is history, the cover letter is the sales pitch